# Cant access AppDelegate class when writing code in pod section

Tags: ios, swift, window, cocoapods

I am writing code in pod section. And this code doesnt work. Pod section doest see AppDelegate class:

```
   if let app = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate, let window = app.window {
         // AppDelegate is unresolved 
   }
```

I want to access window property from AppDelegate class. How can I do it? 
By Pod Section I mean, I am writing framework for via cocoa pod. It means I am writing code in pod section so later I can install it on my project.

Comment: What happens? "doesn't work" is not a description.

Comment: What is a pod section? Where is defined that function? Why do you need get window from a application? May be you can get a window as parameter of the method.

Answer (score 2):

You can directly access window from `UIApplication`

```
let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
```